# bundler error with @connect decorator in react native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I'm getting the following error with my running packager in my react native project when I'm trying to run a debug build on device

```
: bundling failed: SyntaxError /app/js/screens/RootScreen.js: Unexpected token (27:0)
  25 |   };
  26 | }
> 27 | @connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
```

I followed the advice of this blog post https://medium.com/@ivanzotov/adding-es7-decorator-support-to-a-react-native-project-de537e958da0 and added the following to my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"]
}
```

but I still get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the latest auto-generated [React Native Seed](https://reactnativeseed.com/) project with Redux, the preset appears to be named differently. Update your `.babelrc` to this:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"]
}
```